# should I use assets folder or public folder? laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, gulp

***Using Laravel 5.3***

I realized now the view files are under a folder called `resources` and there's an `assets` folder which has `js` folder in it.
`public` folder still exists

I have read a few other posts saying it's up to you either I want to put my `js` or `css` under `public` or `assets`

I also know that when using `gulp` files are directed under `public` which is changeable.

I am wondering if I put my files under the `assets` then compile under `public` do I have to run the compile each time when I test my scripts? If not, what should I put as the `src` in my html?

Comment: You can run gulp watch to continuously re-compile assets if something gets changed. Only public folder is exposed

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in your public folder. If you use `URL::asset('path/to/file')` it will return [...]app/public/path/to/file and not the resources path as well.

The resources folder you mentioned is more for raw assets like SASS, LESS, etc.